# Swift link Image data from Parse array using segues to secondViewController

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Here is my code, i am trying to use the "prepareForSegue" function to send an image from tableViewController (firstViewController) to my detailedViewController (secondViewController). I have managed to populate my firstViewController from the parse cloud successfully and I have managed to get my secondViewController Labels to update, but i can not get the imageView to update. I have posted my code below

firstViewController

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:      AnyObject?) {

let eventDetailVC: EventDetailsVC = segue.destinationViewController as!  EventDetailsVC
if let selectedArrayIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row {

    eventDetailVC.detailNameLabel = postedEvents[selectedArrayIndex]
    eventDetailVC.detailAddressLabel = postedAddress[selectedArrayIndex]
    eventDetailVC.detailCityLabel = postedCity[selectedArrayIndex]
    eventDetailVC.detailStateLabel = postedState[selectedArrayIndex]
    eventDetailVC.detailStartLabel = postedStart[selectedArrayIndex]
    eventDetailVC.detailEndLabel = postedEnd[selectedArrayIndex]
    eventDetailVC.detailPriceLabel = postedPrices[selectedArrayIndex]
    eventDetailVC.detailDescriptionLabel =    postedDescription[selectedArrayIndex]

    // The error is here....i think
    postedImages[selectedArrayIndex].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in

        if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

            eventDetailVC.detailImageView.image =  downloadedImage
        }
    }
}
```

}
secondViewController

```
 var detailNameLabel = String()
 var detailDescriptionLabel = String()
 var detailPriceLabel = String()
 var detailStartLabel = String()
 var detailEndLabel = String()
 var detailAddressLabel = String()
 var detailCityLabel = String()
 var detailStateLabel = String()
 var detailImageView = UIImageView()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

detailName.text = detailNameLabel
detailDescription.text = detailDescriptionLabel
detailPrice.text = detailPriceLabel
detailStart.text = detailStartLabel
detailEnd.text = detailEndLabel
detailAddress.text = detailAddressLabel
detailCity.text = detailCityLabel
detailState.text = detailStateLabel

// its this line below....i think
detailImage.image = detailImageView.image
}
```

Please can someone help me figure this out, Im kinda new to this whole thing

Comment: Move the code from `viewDidLoad` to `viewWillAppear`

Comment: Do not repeatedly ask the same question, please.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where "detailImage" is defined, so this is assuming it is a property on .

Set a breakpoint inside the "getDataInBackgroundWithBlock" completion block to see if and when it is getting called. If it is getting called add "eventDetailVC.detailImage.image = downloadedImage" to the completion block.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the download of the image completes asynchronously, so by the time it has completed, your view controller has already executed the line `detailImage.image = detailImageView.image` with a nil image.

Rather than putting all of the code in your `viewDidLoad`, define `didSet` observers for your properties that set the appropriate UI elements.  This way any time the property is updated it will automatically update the UI element;

Finally, your properties have confusing names, `detailAddressLabel` is actually a string and the UILabel instance seems to be named `detailAddress` - this has caused you to define `detailImageView` as `UIImageView` instead of a UIImage.

My suggested implementation is (after changing the names of IBOutlets and other properties to make more sense):

```
 class someViewController : UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var detailNameLabel : UILabel! {
        didSet {
            self.detailNameLabel?.text=self.detailName
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet var detailDescriptionLabel : UILabel! {
        didSet {
            self.detailDescriptionLabel?.text=self.detailDescription
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet var detailPriceLabel : UILabel! {
        didSet {
            self.detailPriceLabel?.text=self.detailPrice
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet var detailStartLabel : UILabel! {
        didSet {
            self.detailStartLabel?.text=self.detailStart
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet var detailEndLabel : UILabel! {
        didSet {
            self.detailEndLabel?.text=self.detailEnd
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet var detailAddressLabel : UILabel! {
        didSet {
            self.detailAddressLabel?.text=self.detailAddress
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet var detailCityLabel : UILabel! {
        didSet {
            self.detailCityLabel?.text=self.detailCity
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet var detailImageView : UIImageView! {
        didSet {
            self.detailImageView?.image=self.detailImage
        }
    }

    var detailName : String = "" {
        didSet {
            self.detailNameLabel?.text=self.detailName
        }
    }

    var detailDescription : String = "" {
        didSet {
            self.detailDescriptionLabel?.text=self.detailDescription
        }
    }
    var detailPrice : String = "" {
        didSet {
            self.detailPriceLabel?.text=self.detailPrice
        }
    }
    var detailStart : String  = "" {
        didSet {
            self.detailStartLabel?.text=self.detailStart
        }
    }
    var detailEnd : String = "" {
        didSet {
            self.detailEndLabel?.text=self.detailEnd
        }
    }
    var detailAddress: String = "" {
        didSet {
            self.detailAddressLabel?.text=self.detailAddress
        }
    }
    var detailCity : String = "" {
        didSet {
            self.detailCityLabel?.text=self.detailCity
        }
    }
    var detailImage : UIImage? {
        didSet {
            self.detailImageView?.image=self.detailImage
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when i get into the didSet method i get a "EXC BAD EXCEPTION" error...is there something im missing?

Comment: Are your IBOutlets connected?  You will get an exception if any of them are nil.

Comment: they are all connected. I am looking at the debugging and my detailName gets set...but nothing else

Comment: Which line causes the exception? Try single stepping through to see where it occurs

Comment: the very first didset method. I the app runs, then when i go to access the detailViewController it sends me to the exception. I cannot step through it. I doesnt seem to be changing the label text x

Comment: When you step into the did set see what is nil.

Comment: all the labels are nil, but like a mentioned the detailName variable changes to the name

Comment: Yes, but because the UILabels are force unwrapped there will be an exception if they haven't been set yet. Have you removed the code from viewDidLoad and just left it in the prepareForSegue?

Comment: yes i removed the code from the viewDidLoad, i changed  eventDetailVC.detailNameLabel = postedEvents[selectedArrayIndex] to  eventDetailVC.detailName = postedEvents[selectedArrayIndex] because i was getting an error "cannot subscript a value of Type String"

Comment: Hmm. When I tested this the UILabel had been set by the time the didSet code ran.

Comment: any last suggestions? Once this is solved my app is complete, ive been working on this for 3 days now! i cant figure it out. Does it change anything if im importing data from parse?

Comment: You can change the IBOutlets to optionAl (? Instead of !) and check that it isn't nil in the didset

Comment: I keep messing around with things but every time in my error log i get this, "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" Does this mean anything? Also I tried printing something out in the didset method before i change any values, and it doesnt seem to pass that either.

Comment: now i get an uncaught exception with the delegate!! agghhhh

Comment: Any time you use ! You will get an exception if it is nil. If there is a chance it could be nil use ?